# Routing child to parent is not working when navigates in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 5.1.0, and I have an issue with the routing system, let me explain:

In my app-routing module I have an url `/api` that lazy loads another module, in that lazy loaded module I have the next routing implementation:

***api-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ApisComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumbs: 'APIs',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ApiListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ApiDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
          api: ApiResolverService
        },
        data: {
          breadcrumbs: '{{ api.title }}',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The important thing here is the `data` param that the Router receives.

In my app I have a generic error behaviour that when an exception is throwed I have a errorHandler class that catch the error and redirects to another url: `/error`, this is the handler code:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    const routerService = this.injector.get(Router);
    routerService.navigateByUrl('/error', { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
}
```

The problem is, when an exception is throwed inside `/api` and `handleError` is executed, I see my generic error page rendered with the breadcrumb loaded in the last route: `/api` by `data` param.

Is there any way to set the Router to reset data when is loaded? or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

At this point I thought the problem was due to `data` param, but now I see that it's not the problem. Let me show my `error.component` that is rendered when Router loads `/error`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('snapshot trace');
    console.log(this.route.snapshot);
  }
}
```

I have included in the onInit component method, a trace of `ActivatedRoute` snapshot to see what it has, and the thing is that trace is not showing when errorHandler navigates from `/api` to `/error`.

But if I load directly `/error` the trace is showed, so for any reason the error component is not instanciated correctly in the first scenario (navigate from `/api` to `/error`)

---

**UPDATE**
I have upgraded to angular 5.2.9 and the problem still happens.

Comment: I’m not sure you can inject the router like this. I think it’s a different copy of the router. You need to inject it normally and use a factory provider

Comment: Thanks for comment! It is the correct way to inject in an ErrorHandler because it is created before the providers and need to use injector, if you don't you will have a circular dependency error

Comment: That’s what I thought but this is still the incorrect way. You should use a factory function

Comment: I don't know what you meant, maybe you are talking about a different and right way, but this way is correct, I have solved my problem, by the way, thanks for your comments.

Comment: hidden dependencies are always bad practice, ref: angular docs

Comment: Factory providers are not used for this purpose, the problem here is when bootstrap, this error class is created before providers. https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a By the way, the main problem here was not about injection

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have solved the problem using NgZone, I think the "timing" routing problem that angular has involve the render error component out of angular zone, so, the AppErrorHandler class looks like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    const routerService = this.injector.get(Router);
    const ngZone = this.injector.get(NgZone);
    ngZone.run(() => {
      routerService.navigate(['/error'], { skipLocationChange: true });
    });
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20112#issuecomment-341474541) a github issue related to my problem

Comment: While this fix worked for me, i want to point out an error i got incase it helps someone. I got " error TS2339: Property 'run' does not exist on type '{}'.". which i managed to fix by strongly typing the variable name ike this - let router: Router = this.injector.get(Router);

Comment: Perfect @Nandun, you have a tslint rule strict for that, thx for the point, I'm sure that it will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: Worked us when this issue appeared after moving to Angular 8

Comment: It woked for me even without `{ skipLocationChange: true }` - this way the url changes normally