# Snackbar position wrong when use errorhandler in angular 5 and material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have custom global error handler

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    handleError(err: any): void {
        var route = this.injector.get(Router);
        var snackBar = this.injector.get(MatSnackBar);
        console.log(err);

        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            var message = ErrorMessages.get(err.status);

            if (route.url.toLowerCase() !== '/login' && err.status === 401) {
                route.navigateByUrl('/login');
            }

            if (message.length > 0) {
                snackBar.open(message, "x", { duration: 5000, horizontalPosition: "center", verticalPosition: "bottom" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The position of snackbar is **not** at vertically bottom and horizontally centered.

[image]

If I use snackbar in http interceptor, it is displayed correctly

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private route: Router, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
        var url = this.route.url;
        var isAuthenticated = this.loginService.isAuthenticated();

        var authHeader = ``;
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            authHeader = `Bearer ${this.loginService.getToken()}`;
        }

        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: authHeader,
                ApiKey: "aaa"
            }
        });

        return next.handle(req)
            .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {

                }
            }, (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    var message = ErrorMessages.get(err.status);

                    if (this.route.url.toLowerCase() !== '/login' && err.status === 401) {
                        this.route.navigateByUrl('/login');
                    }

                    if (message.length > 0) {
                        this.snackBar.open(message, "x", { duration: 5000, horizontalPosition: "center", verticalPosition: "bottom" });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Why ?

Comment: Why factory affects snackbar position?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in the route, not in the snackbar. Take a look to my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325743/routing-child-to-parent-is-not-working-when-navigates-in-angular/49713144#49713144 I have solved a issue in the errorhandler using the ngzone module, maybe if you open the snackbar inside the ngzone fix the problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had this problem too but was **not** using [HTTPInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) (or any other interceptors).

I was however creating and dispatching the [SnackBar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) with a custom component using `openFromComponent` - this is when the problem occurred (previously, I was using `open`).

**Running from within a zone fixed my problem.**

You'll need to update the component constructor to include [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) and [MatSnackBar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) services:

```
constructor(
    private readonly msb: MatSnackBar,
    private readonly zone: NgZone
  ) { }
```

...and then launch:

```
private openErrorSnackBar(messages: string[]) {

    this.zone.run(() => {

      this.msb.openFromComponent(ErrorSnackComponent, {
        data: messages,
        horizontalPosition: 'end',
        duration: 5000,
      });

    });

  }
```

I've wrapped my code in a convenience function which accepts an array of strings (error messages) to display within the Snackbar Component,

Comment: For me `openFromComponent` doesn't show text, but `open` does

Comment: I did not need to use `openFromComponent`, but the `zone.run()` led me to my solution