# SnackBar not showing when used inside HTTPInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, snackbar

I am trying to write a Global HTTP Interceptor which intercepts all HTTP Responses,inspects the responses and (if certain conditions are met), show a snackbar.

I cant seem to get the snackbar to show. If I put a breakpoint at the .open() line, i see the snackbar appear for a brief moment but without any text and off-center.

**Interceptor:**

```
import { Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {    
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
//import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class TMCErrorHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar,private injector: Injector, private zone: NgZone){}
    /**
      * @param HttpRequest<any> request - The intercepted request
      * @param HttpHandler next - The next interceptor in the pipeline
      * @return Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
      */
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const started = Date.now();
        return next.handle(request)
            // add error handling
            .pipe(
                tap(event => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {                        
                        if (this.isError(event.body)){
                            this.handleError(event.body);                                          
                        }
                    }
                }, error => {
                    console.error('NICE ERROR', error)
                })
            );
    }
    isError(response: any): any {
        return (typeof (response) == "object"
            && typeof (response.MESSAGE) != "undefined"
            && typeof (response.STATUS) != "undefined"
            && typeof (response.CODE) != "undefined"
            && response.STATUS === "error"
        );
    }
    handleError(error: any): any {
        this.snackBar = this.injector.get(MatSnackBar);
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.snackBar.open("hiiiiii");
          });
    }
}
```

I have tried taking out the zone, and not using the injector. No change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snackbar position wrong when use errorhandler in angular 5 and material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101912/snackbar-position-wrong-when-use-errorhandler-in-angular-5-and-material)

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled upon the answer somehow, cloning the request made the snackbar work correctly. Strange.

I understand the need to clone the request from modifiability/chainability point of view, but for that to impact the snackbar will need better minds than mine to explain.

So in summary, to those who wander into this strange Nick of the woods, adding this line to the top of the intercept () function made it work:

request = request.clone();